# Combining two types of Category Filter in Google Charts API

Tags: google-visualization

I wanted to enable users to filter the results being displayed on the chart. Google API provides CategoryFilter which enforces filtering by rows. Here is my code which works perfectly fine

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the Ajax API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['controls']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);

     var countryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'negeri',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      filterColumnLabel: 'Negeri',
      ui: {
        labelStacking: 'vertical',
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: true
      }
    },
    // Define an initial state, i.e. a set of metrics to be initially selected.
    state: {'selectedValues': ['Kedah', 'Johor']}
  });


        var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'ColumnChart',
        containerId: 'chart_div',
        options: {
            title: 'Statistik Negeri vs. Kategori Sukan',
            width: 1000,
            height: 1000,
            hAxis: {title: 'Negeri', titleTextStyle: {color: 'blue'}},
            vAxis: {title: 'Jumlah Kategori', titleTextStyle: {color: 'blue'}}
        }
    });




     // Create the dashboard.
  new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
    // Configure the controls so that:
    // - the 'Country' selection drives the 'Region' one,
    // - the 'Region' selection drives the 'City' one,
    // - and finally the 'City' output drives the chart
    bind(countryPicker, chart).
    // Draw the dashboard
    draw(data);
    }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="dashboard">
<div id="negeri"></div>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However in my datatable, I would also want to filter by columns. These two types of filtering should work together. (dependent; by bind() function). I have referred to @asgallant http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/WaUu2/ and that is the feature that I wanted to combine with.

How can I possibly combine them? I have tried combining setChartView() by @asgallant with google's dashboard() but it's not working.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Load the Ajax API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['controls']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

      // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);

      var columnsTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    columnsTable.addColumn('number', 'colIndex');
    columnsTable.addColumn('string', 'colLabel');
    var initState= {selectedValues: []};
    // put the columns into this data table (skip column 0)
    for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
        columnsTable.addRow([i, data.getColumnLabel(i)]);
        // you can comment out this next line if you want to have a default selection other than the whole list
        initState.selectedValues.push(data.getColumnLabel(i));
    }

     var countryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'negeri',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      filterColumnLabel: 'Negeri',
      ui: {
        labelStacking: 'vertical',
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: true
      }
    },
    // Define an initial state, i.e. a set of metrics to be initially selected.
    state: {'selectedValues': ['Kedah', 'Johor']}
  });

var columnFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
        containerId: 'colFilter_div',
        dataTable: columnsTable,
        options: {
            filterColumnLabel: 'colLabel',
            ui: {
                label: 'Kategori Sukan',
                allowTyping: false,
                allowMultiple: true,
                allowNone: false,
                selectedValuesLayout: 'belowStacked'
            }
        },
        state: initState
    });


        var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'ColumnChart',
        containerId: 'chart_div',
        options: {
            title: 'Statistik Negeri vs. Kategori Sukan',
            width: 1000,
            height: 1000,
            hAxis: {title: 'Negeri', titleTextStyle: {color: 'blue'}},
            vAxis: {title: 'Jumlah Kategori', titleTextStyle: {color: 'blue'}}
        }
    });




     // Create the dashboard.
  new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
    // Configure the controls so that:
    // - the 'Country' selection drives the 'Region' one,
    // - the 'Region' selection drives the 'City' one,
    // - and finally the 'City' output drives the chart
    bind(countryPicker, columnFilter).
    bind(columnFilter, chart).
    // Draw the dashboard
    draw(data);
    }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="dashboard">
<div id="negeri"></div>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to bind your `countryPicker` filter to the chart as normal, but do not bind the `columnFilter` control to anything - the `setChartView` function handles everything for the `columnFilter`.  You need to tweak a couple other lines to make it work with a dashboard, but nothing major.  This is what it should look like:

```
function drawChart() {
    // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(<?=$jsonTable?>);

    var columnsTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    columnsTable.addColumn('number', 'colIndex');
    columnsTable.addColumn('string', 'colLabel');
    var initState= {selectedValues: []};
    // put the columns into this data table (skip column 0)
    for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
        columnsTable.addRow([i, data.getColumnLabel(i)]);
        // you can comment out this next line if you want to have a default selection other than the whole list
        initState.selectedValues.push(data.getColumnLabel(i));
    }

    var countryPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
        containerId: 'negeri',
        dataTable: data,
        options: {
            filterColumnLabel: 'Negeri',
            ui: {
                labelStacking: 'vertical',
                allowTyping: false,
                allowMultiple: true
            }
        },
        // Define an initial state, i.e. a set of metrics to be initially selected.
        state: {'selectedValues': ['Kedah', 'Johor']}
    });

    var columnFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
        containerId: 'colFilter_div',
        dataTable: columnsTable,
        options: {
            filterColumnLabel: 'colLabel',
            ui: {
                label: 'Kategori Sukan',
                allowTyping: false,
                allowMultiple: true,
                allowNone: false,
                selectedValuesLayout: 'belowStacked'
            }
        },
        state: initState
    });

    var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        chartType: 'ColumnChart',
        containerId: 'chart_div',
        options: {
            title: 'Statistik Negeri vs. Kategori Sukan',
            width: 1000,
            height: 1000,
            hAxis: {title: 'Negeri', titleTextStyle: {color: 'blue'}},
            vAxis: {title: 'Jumlah Kategori', titleTextStyle: {color: 'blue'}}
        }
    });

    // Create the dashboard.
    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard')).
    bind(countryPicker, chart);

    function setChartView () {
        var state = columnFilter.getState();
        var row;
        var view = {
            columns: [0]
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < state.selectedValues.length; i++) {
            row = columnsTable.getFilteredRows([{column: 1, value: state.selectedValues[i]}])[0];
            view.columns.push(columnsTable.getValue(row, 0));
        }
        // sort the indices into their original order
        view.columns.sort(function (a, b) {
            return (a - b);
        });
        chart.setView(view);
        chart.draw();
    }
    google.visualization.events.addListener(columnFilter, 'statechange', setChartView);
    var runOnce = google.visualization.events.addListener(dashboard, 'ready', function () {
        google.visualization.events.removeListener(runOnce);
        setChartView();
    });

    columnFilter.draw();
    dashboard.draw(data);
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChart});
```

Comment: I have used your suggested code, and have added the div id of columnFilter in the html body. However something might have gone wrong somewhere, the columnFilter did not appear on the chart like the countryPicker did.

Comment: Sorry, you need to add a draw call for the column filter.  I'll edit the answer with the call.

Comment: Gentlemen, would either of you kindly provide some example data? I would like to understand how this code works, and few lines of input data would be very helpful. @asgallant